# How does one brake while drifting with the Nunchuck controls?

Tags: mario-kart-8

Version 4.0 of Mario Kart 8 added 200cc, and with it, the ability to brake while drifting for sharper turns. (I guess maybe this was in the game already, but they certainly added feedback with sparks for doing so in 200cc because of how important it ends up being.)

The problem is, the "brake" and "drift" buttons are both the B button for the Nunchuck control setup. While a specific change was noted for the Wiimote-alone setup (hold B+1+2 all at once), none was given for Nunchuck users.

So how are Nunchuck users supposed to brake while drifting?

Answer (score 9):

With that controller setup, you can't. Kind of a bummer because it's the same one I use. The problem is that with a wiimote + nunchuck setup, B means "drift" when you are holding down the accelerator, and "brake" when you are not. But in order to brake-drift, you need to be holding down the accelerator, drifting, AND braking...impossible with this control scheme.

Further reading: http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/700050-mario-kart-8/71683644